# Why were the identities of these two characters switched?

Tags: warhammer-40k

**Warning! Mild spoilers for the novel *Angron***

The World Eaters are famous for the Butcher's Nails, an implant similar to the one that has been implanted to their Primarch Angron when he was a slave on Nuceria. This implant enhanced the rage and anger of his bearer, and could induce a state of frenzy.

The novel *Angron* tells the story of the Ghenna Massacre and how the chief Apothicary Gahlan Surlak created a version of the Butcher's Nails that could successfully be implanted into the brain of a Marine and how to mass-produce it.

> Most Earth-born World Eaters, under the led of the centurion Mago, considered that this would lead to the doom of their Legion, and decided to sabotage the work of Gahlan Surlak.

In Chapter 19, two Marines

> infiltrated the Apothecarion to destroy the prototype of the Butcher's Nails. However, the plot is foiled by Surlak that had anticipated the treachery.

In the French version of the book (bought around December 2019), the chapter is told from the viewpoint of

> brother Hanno, the dimachurias of the 18th company. The other Marine's name is not given, but we know it is a Techmarine. ("Hanno se retourna lorsque le Techmarine s'effondra en tas". *Hanno turned back when the Techmarine felt on the ground*.). Surlak kills first the Techmarine, before poisoning Hanno and giving him a painful death with his Chirurgeon drill ("Cette toxine te tuera, reprit Gahlan. Mais je me demande... si cette trahison ne reclame pas un chatiment plus douloureux" *This toxin will kill you, Gahlan added. But I wonder ... if this treachery does not require a more painful punishment*)

As I didn't know what the title of this Marine meant in the organization of the World Eaters, I checked Lexicanum to [discover](https://wh40k.lexicanum.com/wiki/Gahlan_Surlak) that in the English version (I guess)

> that it is the Techmarine Korit that is poisoned and killed with cruelty by Gahlan Surlak.

The descriptions of the scene match but only differ by the identity of the Marine involved. From Lexicanum,

> his caused the Terran veteran Mago to attempt to send the Techmarine Korit to sabotage Surlak's work within his lab, but the Apothecary was ready for the attempt and subdued Korit with a poison dart (...). Surlak revealed his sadistic side as he took pleasure in giving Korit an agonizing death with his Chirurgeon drill, justifying it as punishment for treachery.

The two characters are distinct, as they both appear in the Dramatis Personae. This is not a typo since the name of the Marine is written several times in the chapter and his specialty in the legion is clearly stated,

This is not a big deal but it is odd to me. **Was it explained why the identity of the character was changed?**

Edit: The [Warhammer 40k wikia](https://warhammer40k.fandom.com/wiki/Gahlan_Surlak) agrees with Lexicanum.

Comment: Translation error?

Comment: @Yasskier: not quite. The name of the protagonist of the chapter is used several times, and his specialty in the World Eaters is clear. His companion is unnamed but his specialty is also clearly identified. That's hard to believe it was not intentional.

Comment: possibly a black library editor disagreement about what would make more sense